# Can't get an authorization code from spring-security-oauth2-authorization-server 1.0.0

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, oauth-2.0

I can't get a authorization code from http request from browser  using link `http://localhost:9000/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=sandwich-admin-client&redirect_uri=http://127.0.0.1:9090/login/oauth2/code/sandwich-admin-client&-scope=writeIngredients+deleteIngredients`.

I believe I have to see code parameter in browser’s address bar.

Once I sign in (user has ROLE_ADMIN) and then "Submit Consent" I receive link `http://127.0.0.1:9090/login/oauth2/code/sandwich-admin-client?error=access_denied&error_description=OAuth 2.0 Parameter: client_id&error_uri=https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6749#section-4.1.2.1` and refusal to connect. It is client id error, but it is the same as configured in the link.

Is my linked is wrong or is there any mistake in my code?

Here is my AuthorizationServerConfig class:

```
@Configuration(proxyBeanMethods = false)
public class AuthorizationServerConfig {

    @Bean
    @Order(2)
    public SecurityFilterChain defaultSecurityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http)
            throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeHttpRequests(authorize -> authorize.anyRequest().authenticated())
                .formLogin(Customizer.withDefaults());

        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    UserDetailsService userDetailsService(UserRepository userRepo) {
        return username -> userRepo.findByUsername(username);
    }
    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    @Order(1)
    public SecurityFilterChain authorizationServerSecurityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http)
            throws Exception {
        OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfiguration.applyDefaultSecurity(http);
        http.getConfigurer(OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfigurer.class)
                .oidc(Customizer.withDefaults());   // Enable OpenID Connect 1.0
        http
                .exceptionHandling((exceptions) -> exceptions
                        .authenticationEntryPoint(
                                new LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint("/login"))
                )
                .oauth2ResourceServer(OAuth2ResourceServerConfigurer::jwt);

        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    public RegisteredClientRepository registeredClientRepository(PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder) {
        RegisteredClient registeredClient = RegisteredClient.withId(UUID.randomUUID().toString())
                .clientId("sandwich-admin-client")
                .clientSecret(passwordEncoder.encode("secret"))
                .clientAuthenticationMethod(ClientAuthenticationMethod.CLIENT_SECRET_BASIC)
                .authorizationGrantType(AuthorizationGrantType.AUTHORIZATION_CODE)
                .authorizationGrantType(AuthorizationGrantType.REFRESH_TOKEN)
                .redirectUri("http://127.0.0.1:9090/login/oauth2/code/sandwich-admin-client")
                .scope("writeIngredients")
                .scope("deleteIngredients")
                .scope(OidcScopes.OPENID)
                .clientSettings(ClientSettings.builder().requireAuthorizationConsent(true).build())
                .build();
        return new InMemoryRegisteredClientRepository(registeredClient);
    }

    @Bean
    public JWKSource<SecurityContext> jwkSource() {
        KeyPair keyPair = generateRsaKey();
        RSAPublicKey publicKey = (RSAPublicKey) keyPair.getPublic();
        RSAPrivateKey privateKey = (RSAPrivateKey) keyPair.getPrivate();
        RSAKey rsaKey = new RSAKey.Builder(publicKey)
                .privateKey(privateKey)
                .keyID(UUID.randomUUID().toString())
                .build();
        JWKSet jwkSet = new JWKSet(rsaKey);
        return new ImmutableJWKSet<>(jwkSet);
    }

    private static KeyPair generateRsaKey() {
        KeyPair keyPair;
        try {
            KeyPairGenerator keyPairGenerator = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
            keyPairGenerator.initialize(2048);
            keyPair = keyPairGenerator.generateKeyPair();
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            throw new IllegalStateException(ex);
        }
        return keyPair;
    }

    @Bean
    public JwtDecoder jwtDecoder(JWKSource<SecurityContext> jwkSource) {
        return OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfiguration.jwtDecoder(jwkSource);
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthorizationServerSettings authorizationServerSettings() {
        return AuthorizationServerSettings.builder().build();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used Postman and it helped me to get the right URL for an authentification code.
The link is `http://localhost:9000/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=sandwich-admin-client&scope=writeIngredients deleteIngredients&redirect_uri=http://127.0.0.1:9090/login/oauth2/code/sandwich-admin-client`

Postman request is shown on the picture below
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your link is incorrect, there is an extra dash before the "scope" parameter "&-scope".
http://localhost:9000/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=sandwich-admin-client&redirect_uri=http://127.0.0.1:9090/login/oauth2/code/sandwich-admin-client&scope=writeIngredients+deleteIngredients

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).